# MySQL Newbie - What are the components of this query?

Tags: mysql

This is gonna be a dumb question, but I've been working with this code for years and never stopped to understand the what and why....

This is a very typical query I would copy and edit:

```
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_qry_details = sprintf("Select * from table where id = %s", $KTColParam1_qry_details);
$qry_details = mysql_query($query_qry_details, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_qry_details = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_details);
$totalRows_qry_details = mysql_num_rows($qry_details);
```

What do all these rows mean?

The first I know looks up the correct database.  I have this line before each query on the page....do I need this?

The second row ($query_qry_details) is the query itself.  I see that.

Rows 3 and 4 - no clue...

Row 5 is obviously a count of the number rows the query returns.

Thanks in advance as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Shortly:

`mysql_select_db(database_name, link_identifier)` - Sets the cuurent active database on server that is associated with the specified link identifier. 
`sprintf` - Return formatted string which acts as a query. 
`mysql_query` or `die` - Sends a unique query to the database previously specified or exit from query. 
`mysql_fetch_assoc` - Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. 
`mysql_num_rows` - Retrieves the number of rows from a result set.

Comment: You worked with this for years and didn't find the 5 minutes time to look up the php manual?

Comment: Is your comment against my answer or on question :)

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for some plain english on this.  All my queries have this format and I'm trying to figure out if I need it all on the page.